# codnigter PHP echo form_submit error

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

1 - Dont pass variable e don´t login.... why ??

```
<?php echo form_submit('login', 'Login', 'class="btn btn-primary"') ?>
```

2 - Work

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeignighter, but I would be interested in seeing what HTML it creates.  Using codeigniter, could you "view source" to see the HTML it creates, and edit your question to include what it created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"` and `'` are in the wrong place
change

```
<?php echo form_submit('login', 'Login', 'class="btn btn-primary"') ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo form_submit('login', 'Login',"class='btn btn-danger'");?>
```

Comment: Work this, but why this ? 'loginSubmit' and no 'login' only ?

<?php echo form_submit('loginSubmit', 'Login',"class='btn btn-primary'");?>

Comment: If that solved your answer could you mark it as 'Solved'